# How to set scroll position after close image?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'm using photoswipe to generate photo gallery on my website. The gallery is horizontal orientation. How to set position scroll?

JavaScript code

```
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {


    // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
    gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
  //gallery.listen('close', function() { alert('close') });
  //gallery.listen('mouseUsed', function() { });
    gallery.init();
};

// loop through all gallery elements and bind events
var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
    galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
    galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
}

// Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
    openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
}
};
// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
```

Here's [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbaOWq) !